# Order confirmation to Admin not sent on two products

Tags: cartthrob

Strangely, on two specific products only, order confirmation emails are not being sent to the administrators upon a successful order.  I can not find any settings to control whether a order confirmation email is to be sent on a per-product basis.  I've checked spam filters.

I'm using EE 2.7.2 and Cartthrob 2.5.

Thanks for any help.

Bruce

Comment: Strange indeed. My first thought is: does the email contain info about the product? If so maybe there is some bad characters within making the email fail. Try just a generic email without any info.